# How to convert decimal value to character in c language

Tags: c

I have an array of char but values is decimal representation of a character.
example:

```
char bytes[4]={50,48,49,51}
```

how to convert this to get char array like this:

```
char bytes1[4]={2,0,1,3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Input Array for this Question is:

```
char bytes[4]={50,48,49,51}
```

In the Memory, the characters are stored as corresponding **ASCII** values (or any other character encoding scheme, chosen by your compiler): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

For the given input, the **ASCII** Value - Char Mapping is as follows:

```
ASCII Value   ||  Character
48            ||     '0'
49            ||     '1'
50            ||     '2'
51            ||     '3'
```

**Note:**

A. To Convert a Given Character Value to the Corresponding Integer Value:

```
Subtract '0'.

Example: '2' - '0' = (int) 2
```

B. To Convert a Given Integer Value to the Corresponding Character:

```
Add '0'.

Example: 2 + '0' = 50 {ASCII Value for '2'}
```

Print the Character Values for the Given Input Array:

```
int main ()
{
    char bytes[4]={50,48,49,51};  
    int i=0;

    /* Print The Equivalent Character Values */
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {   
        printf ("%c\t", bytes[i]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2       0       1       3
```

Comment: This will have `bytes1 = {50,48,49,51}` as well, you just print it interpreted as a character.

Comment: Not as chars, you will get them as ints. GDB Output: (gdb) p bytes1[0]
$2 = 50 '2'
(gdb) p bytes1[1]
$3 = 48 '0'
(gdb) p bytes1[2]
$4 = 49 '1'
(gdb) p bytes1[3]
$5 = 51 '3'

Comment: Exactly `bytes1[0] = 50` which is the character `'2'`. Op wants `bytes1[0] = 2` etc.

Comment: Desired O/P:: char bytes1[4]={2,0,1,3}. It seems that the OP expects (char)bytes[0] = (char)2 which is what the above code delivers

Comment: Huh? This: `bytes1[i] = ((bytes[i]-'0')%(48))+'0';` does nothing, e.g. `50 - '0' == 2` with ASCII, `2 % 48 == 2` and `2 + '0' == 50`. All that's happening is that `printf ("%c\t", 50);` outputs `2` like you'd expect, all your first loop accomplishes is to make the CPU get a little warmer.

Comment: No, All this is done to save the Final O/P back as characters. 50-'0' is incomplete answer to this question.

Comment: I think you are confused about how C works. Before your loop, you have `char bytes[4]={50,48,49,51}`. After your loop, that's still exactly what you have. It's meaningless to talk about "sav[ing] the Final O/P back as characters" since (1) you don't "save" output, you just output it; and (2) they're characters to begin with, so you don't need to do anything to turn them into characters. The OP may be confused about what he/she wants, but the question as stated is to actually change the `char` array, which your answer does not do.

Comment: Or rather, the OP asks for `char bytes1[4]={2,0,1,3}`, and what your answer actually gives is `char bytes1[4]={50,48,49,51}`, it's just an inefficient way of copying `bytes` to `bytes1`. Your program would give exactly the same output if you replaced `printf ("%c\t", bytes1[i]);` with `printf ("%c\t", bytes[i]);` and dropped all references to `bytes1` altogether.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: I think there is some gap. I have added 2 Comments - to elaborate the Concept. The Question reads: convert decimal to char, I have shown char-'0' for this. Conversion back to char was not needed, since chars are stored as ASCII values & storing char 2 is the same as storing 50, but on saving ASCII 2 to bytes1[] will give you a different character. Both -'0' & '0' are shown here for descriptive purpose only.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: You're still missing the point that `char bytes[4] = {50, 48, 49, 51}; for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { printf("%c\t", bytes[i]); }` does exactly what your program does, without any of the superfluous stuff you've put in the middle. All your first loop does is copy `bytes` to `bytes1`. There is no 'concept' to 'elaborate' - your first loop is just an unnecessary series of steps that don't do anything to address the question. You say "Both -'0' & '0' are shown here for descriptive purpose only" but they're not - if you took them out, you'd get the wrong output.

Answer (score 5):

When you create your array you should use character literals:

```
char bytes[4] = {'2', '0', '1', '3'};
```

These are stored in memory in the character encoding your compiler is using which converts the character to a number.

If you want to get the decimal value represented by the character when read by a human (i.e. '2' -> 2) then you can do `bytes[x] - '0'` assuming the digit characters are adjacent in the character encoding (which is true of ASCII and UTFs at least).

Comment: The decimal digit characters will be contiguous and in order for all character sets allowed by the C standard, so `bytes[x] - '0'` will always be good in a conforming implementation.

Answer (score 2):

if you have an array of chars and want to get their values as integers you can do

```
int a = bytes[0] - '0';
```